# Calling function inside jQuery ajax success response works once but not twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page where I enter the names of cards and the card's details are presented via AJAX. I've removed a lot of code in this example that isn't relevant to the issue and I've tested this simplified code and it reproduces the same error.

The mysterious thing is that it works fine the first run through the `testSelectedCardDetails` function. It calls `setNameCardIsFromField` fine and does what it is meant to do. The second time through it dies with the console showing:

```
Uncaught TypeError: setNameCardIsFromField is not a function
```

What's up with that? I honestly don't know enough about how jQuery works to be able to nail the problem so I turn to the stackoverflow world begging for salvation from this madness. ;)

```js
    function testSelectedCardDetails(cardName) {

        var cardTestInfoArray = [];

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/getCardAndSetDataViaAJAX.php',           
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false, // if set to true then the data doesn't get here fast enough to run commands in 'success'
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { callThis: "testSelectedCardDetails", thisCardName: cardName},
            error: function(data){
                console.log("AJAX failed to get card info.");
            },
            success: function(data) {                   

                $.map(data, function (value) { cardTestInfoArray = value; });
                cardPresentInfo['printings'] = cardTestInfoArray['printings'];

                //automatically set setNameCardIsFrom field
                setNameCardIsFromField(cardPresentInfo['printings']);
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's the function being called:

```js
    function setNameCardIsFromField(setCode) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/getCardAndSetDataViaAJAX.php',           
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            async: false,   // if set to true then the data doesn't get here fast enough to run commands in 'success'
            dataType: 'text',
            data: { callThis: "setNameCardIsFromField", thisSetCode: setCode},
            error: function(data){
                console.log("AJAX failed to get card info.");
            },
            success: function(setName) {
                //console.log(setName);
                setNameCardIsFromField = document.querySelector('#setNameCardIsFrom');
                setNameCardIsFromField.value = setName; 
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the function:

```js
 setNameCardIsFromField = document.querySelector('#setNameCardIsFrom');
```

Assuming it's global (which is generally bad).

Unrelated, but meh on using `async: false`, better to do it right than to hack around it, e.g., callback, promise, whatever.

Comment: I'm so humbled. I really need to learn jQuery properly. Right now I just hack away hoping for happy accidents and get frustrated like this far too often. 

The problem I had with async: true, is that the data isn't back fast enough to work with. I spent hours with an issue like that and when I set it to 'false' it fixed it. What to do? I'd like to do things properly but .... ?

Comment: @ekendra Pass a function containing what you want to do to on `setNameCardIsFromField` success and call it in the `success` handler.